# Segmentation fault caused by repeating pop_back() and push_back()

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

When I run the following code in Clion(an IDE) with c++11. I ran into a segmentation fault. But if I delete the if statement, add else before pop_back, remove push_back, or remove pop_back(do them separately). There would be no error. So why there would be a segmentation fault and why doing any of the above would eliminate the error?

```
#include "vector"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> test;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
        if(i % 2 == 0)
            test.push_back(i);
        test.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Edit: Some people say it's because pop_back from empty vector, but if I remove push_back() there won't be any problem(even if I push_back some elements before the loop).

Comment: You push_back for even numbers only but you pop_back for all. Obviously, there are more pop_backs than push_backs. According to [std::vector::pop_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/pop_back): _Calling pop_back on an empty container results in undefined behavior._

Comment: OT: It's `<vector>` instead of `"vector"`

Comment: Stepping through the code in a debugger would quickly alert you to this imbalance of pushes and pops.

Comment: Try to put `assert(test.size() > 0);` before `test.pop_back()`.

Comment: BTW: what is your code supposed to do?

Comment: But if I remove the push_back() and only have pop_back(), IDE won't report any problem.

Comment: @VagenteKing Undefined behavior includes not reporting any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are popping from the vector when it is empty. Using `pop_back()` from an empty vector results in **undefined behaviour** which means:

- your program could crash
- your program could print some nonesens
- your program could continue normally
- your program could continue normally, but have some other strange seemingly unrelated behaviour later
- or some other behaviour

Consider this code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<int> test;
    
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
      test.push_back(i);

    if (test.empty())
      cout << "stack is empty" << endl;
    else
      test.pop_back();
  }
}
```

Comment: But if I delete push_back() and only have pop_back(), there won't be segmentation fault. The program would run normally and return 0.

Comment: @VagenteKing __undefined behaviour__ includes "apparently working fine".

Comment: *seemingly unrelated behaviour later* and even earlier!